# How do i plot a bar graphic with the groupby made column

Tags: python, plotly, data-science

I'm an Environmental Engineer, trying to make a leap change to the data science area which interests me more.

I'm new to Python, I work at a company that evaluates air quality data and I think that if I automate the analysis, I should save some time.

I've imported the CSV files with environmental data from the past month, did some filter in that just to make sure that the data were okay and did a groupby just analyse the data day-to-day (I need that in my report for the regulatory agency).

The step by step of what I did:

```
medias = tabela.groupby(by=["Data"]).mean()
display (tabela)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgvpq.png)

As you can see there's a column named `Data`, but when I do the info check it not recognizes the `Data` as a column.

```
print (medias.info())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEUyL.png)

How can I solve this? I need to plot some graphs with the concentration of rain and dust per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping, please do a reset index

```
medias = tabela.groupby(by=["Data"]).mean()
medias = medias.reset_index()
```